# R portfolio specific regression with specific & common coefficients

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, portfolio

After days of searching and trying different things in R, i am running out of ideas for my problem and search terms to look for. If there is already an answer to my problem, i apologize for asking my question. So far, I couldn't find one.

I'm currently doing a regression for financial data of bonds. Objective of my regression is to determine if two portfolios of bonds are showing significant different yields. 
I´m controlling for 4 variables (V1 to V4) to control for other sources of risk.

The regression formula is the following:

```
ield(p)=∝(p)+ 1(p)*V1+2(p)*V2(,)+3*V3(p)+4*V4(p)
```

`(p)` indicates a portfolio-specific value.

The dependent variable (`Yield`) is portfolio-specific.

Note that `V1` & `V2` have portfolio-specific coefficients and common variable values, 
while `V3` & `V4` have common coefficients and portfolio-specific variable values.

Also the intercept needs to be a portfolio-specific value.

How can i transform the mentioned regression equation to R? 
Especially, how can i get portfolio-specific coefficients for `V1` & `V2` and common coefficients for `V3` & `V4`?

I have no problem with doing an "stand-alone" regression for each portfolio via

```
Regression <- lm(Yield ~ V1 +V2 + V3+ V4)
```

Any advice or suggestions will be appreciated.

Kind regards,

Simon

Comment: Not sure I understand? If `V1` and `V2` are the same but you want separate coefficients the above is fine, but if `V3 `+ `V4` are to be forced to have the same coefficient the just arithmetically make a new column of `V3` plus `V4` e.g. `V3_4` . The your model is `Yield ~ V1+ V2 + V3_4` Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: See Sixiang.Hu answers for a probably better description of my problem. Sorry for my unclear description.

Comment: @dakofla, are you still looking for an answer to this question?

Comment: @Julius thanks for asking. I´m fine with the provided answer. Should I close the question then?

Comment: To be honest, i discarded the described approach. I now conduct a model with "portfolio-specific" coefficients for each variable and don´t use any offset term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of your problem is that:

1. parameters of `v1` and `v2` needs to be portfolio specific
2. parameters of `v3` and `v4` needs to be the same for different portfolio
3. your data contains many (>1) different portfolio
4. linear regression would be your chosen methods for analysis

Based on those assumptions, you can fit `v3` and `v4` first, and then using the output (as offset) to fit `v1` and `v2` for each of your portolio

It is something like:

```
# fit the first model to decide the parameters of v3 and v4 (beta3 and beta4)    
model1 <- lm(Yield~V3+V4)

# Create offset which "frozen" the parameters of v3 and v4
offset_term <- beta3*V3 + beta4*v4

# fit final model with offset for each of your porfolio data
# assuming index_p1 is the row index of your portfolio 1, and index_p2 is for portfolio 2, then:
final_model_portfolio1 <- lm(Yield[index_p1]~V1[index_p1]+V2[index_p1]+offset(offset_term[index_p1]))
final_model_portfolio2 <- lm(Yield[index_p2]~V1[index_p2]+V2[index_p2]+offset(offset_term[index_p2]))
```

Comment: I think you understood my problem correctly. I will try your answer and see if it works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I´m not 100% sure this is what i need. Since V3 & V4 are also portfoliospecific, i´ll have to do model1 for each portfolio (2 portfolios) and then create the offset term for each portfolio. From my point of view,  there isn't a difference to doing "stand-alone" regression for each portfolio. Also I still have 2 "final-regressions-models" with different R². Is it possible to do in one regression equatation?

Comment: @dakofla, `v3` and `v4` is not portfolio specific, as I use all data for estimating the parameters.  The `offset_term` is not portfolio specific as well.  This is based on the assumption that your data has a structure that all portfolio data are appended together in a row-wise

Comment: I think i got you now. It works from a technical standpoint, but I´m not sure it makes sense to do the regression this way from a "financial" standpoint. Nonetheless, I really appreciate your effort! Thanks again. I´ll talk to my thesis counselor and see what he thinks. :)